# Bracket Injection when Concatenating String

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, concatenation

I have a *python 3* program that currently runs extremely well for one part.  I am calculating the area and perimeter of a rectangle (drawn with `graphics.py`) and concatenating the results into one string.  Below is my current code

```
val = "The perimeter is" , str(2*(height + width)), " and the area is   ", str(height*width)
```

When I output it to the page using `graphics.py`, the result shows up as something like the following.

```
{The perimeter is} 215 { and the area is } 616
```

How can I get an output that does not have the brackets in the middle of my text?  Even without `str()`, the brackets exist, which is not the ideal result.  The ideal result is below.

`The perimeter is 215 and the area is 616`

If I use `+` instead of `,`, I get the error `Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`, so that hasn't worked for me either.

Any help would be great!

Comment: You seem to be confusing arguments to `print()`, string concatenation, and `tuple`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `,` in your variable definition, you are creating a tuple not a string. Hence when you do -

```
val = "The perimeter is" , str(2*(height + width)), " and the area is   ", str(height*width)
```

`val` is a `tuple` , this could most probably be the reason for the brackets. I would suggest using `str.format` to create a string. Example -

```
val = "The perimeter is {}  and the area is {}".format(2*(height + width),height*width)
```

Answer (score 1):

In python the plus sign "+" can be used to concatenate strings.

Try

```
val = "The perimeter is " + str(2*(height + width)) + " and the area is " + str(height*width)
```

Comment: If you concat a unicode variable with a str the resulting type will be unicode, which can cause unexpected things. Probably safer to use `format` or the newer f strings unless you know the types are the same or the libraries you are working with are unicode friendly - which they all should be but reality is not always ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't create a concatenated string. `val` becomes a `tuple` containing strings and integers. `graphics.py` seems to show the brackets to indicate where each string element begins/ends.

Python has string formatting for use cases like yours:

```
val = "The perimeter is {} and the area is {}".format(2*(height + width), (height*width))
```

See https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#format-string-syntax for details on the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good use case for string formatting as it would give you greater flexibility on how the result is displayed.

For example:

```
val_string_2dec = 'The perimeter is {perimeter:0.2f} and the area is {area:0.2f}'
val = val_string_2dec.format(perimeter=2*(height+width), area=height*width)
print(val)
# outputs
The perimeter is 215.00 and the area is 616.00
```

[For a full list of formatting options, head over to the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)